# Why is the error not thrown in this code?

Tags: javascript, error-handling

This is my code (Javascript):

```
function getNumbers(){
    var numberString = document.getElementById("numbers").value;
    var actualNumbers = [];
    var flowIndex = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < numberString.length; i++){
        if(numberString.charAt(i) != " " && numberString.charAt(i) != "\," && numberString.charAt(i) != "\t"){
            actualNumbers[flowIndex] = parseInt(numberString.charAt(i));
            flowIndex++;
        }
        else continue;
    }
    return actualNumbers;
}

function division(){
    try{
        var answer = getNumbers()[0] / getNumbers()[1];
        if(getNumbers()[1] == 0)
            throw "bad";
    }
    catch(error){
        throw error.description + "Division by zero error";
    }
    finally{
        return answer;
    }
}
```

I have a function `getNumbers()` which returns an array, with `array[0] = 1` and `array[1] = 0`.  Now, I want to throw an exception "bad" when `array[1] == 0`. But, neither the `try` exception nor the `catch` exception is being thrown, but the finally clause is working. What is the problem?

NOTE: On division by zero, no exception is being thrown, instead answer is coming out to be `Infinity`. getNumbers() is working properly.

Comment: can you please add the body of the `getNumbers()` function?

Comment: why are you calling three times `getNumbers()`? maybe assign the reuslt once to a variable and use the variable.

Comment: this code should throw "Division by zero", because this occurs before your condition.

Comment: @Burki, interestingly, no error occurs on division by zero. The answer is `Infinity`

Comment: `parsInt` has no base.

Comment: I think, logically, `if` statement should be **before** `answer` definition

Comment: @Burki: In JavaScript, `x / 0` is `Infinity`, not an error.

Comment: @hindmost, I did that before, but it crashes the working of the finally clause, otherwise you are right

Comment: @T.J.Crowder , exactly, that is why I made a custom error

Comment: Frankly I don't see the point of using exception in the given simple code.

Comment: @hindmost, me too, but I recently started error handling, so I was just giving it a practice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exception **is** getting thrown, but then you're suppressing the exception by doing this:

```
finally {
    return answer;
}
```

The `finally` clause gets final say. If you `return` from it, that suppresses the exception and makes the function complete normally.

One way to fix it is to remove the `finally` clause and put the `return answer;` inside your `try`.

---

Just FWIW, some other notes as comments:

```
function getNumbers(){
    var numberString = document.getElementById("numbers").value;
    var actualNumbers = [];
    var flowIndex = 0;

    // You might consider splitting the string into an array of one-character strings so you
    // aren't constantly calling a method (`charAt`), like this:
    //     `var chars = numberString.split("");`
    // Then index into `chars`

    // N.B. `let` is an ES2015 (ES6) feature not all JavaScript engines have as it's new;
    // the rest of your code is using the older `var`
    // --v
    for (let i = 0; i < numberString.length; i++){
        // No need to escape the comma --------------------------------v
        if(numberString.charAt(i) != " " && numberString.charAt(i) != "\," && numberString.charAt(i) != "\t"){
            actualNumbers[flowIndex] = parseInt(numberString.charAt(i));
            flowIndex++;
        }
        // No need for the `else continue;` at all
        else continue;
        // In the above, you regularly call `charAt` four times when once would have been sufficient.
        // You might also consider a `switch`
    }
    return actualNumbers;
}

function division(){
    try{
        // Rather than calling `getNumbers` three separate times, call it once and remember its return value
        // doing the calculation should be AFTER checking [1] for 0, not before
        var answer = getNumbers()[0] / getNumbers()[1];
        if(getNumbers()[1] == 0)
            throw "bad";                    // Recommend using Error, e.g.: `throw new Error("bad")`
        // Move the `return answer;` here
    }
    catch(error){
        // You've thrown a string, it doesn't have a `description` property
        // Separately: Why throw something above, just to catch it here and throw something else?
        throw error.description + "Division by zero error";
    }
    // Remove the finally
    finally{
        return answer;
    }
}
```

Again just FWIW, I'd probably put responsibility for getting the value from the `input` in `division` (or even in the thing calling `division`) rather than in `getNumbers`, and use `/\d/.test(...)` to test if a character is a digit, since there are lots of non-digits that aren't `" "`, `","`, or `"\t"`. And once we know they're digits, we can use `+ch` instead of `parseInt` to convert them (but with this input, it's just a style choice [well, there's a performance implication, but 99.99% of the time, that doesn't matter]).

So perhaps:

```
function getNumbers(str) {
    var numbers = [];
    str.split("").forEach(function(ch) {
        if (/\d/.test(ch)) {
            numbers.push(+ch);
        }
    });
    return numbers;
}

function division() {
    var numbers = getNumbers(document.getElementById("numbers").value);
    if (numbers[1] == 0) {
        throw new Error("Division by zero error");
    }
    return numbers[0] / numbers[1];
}
```

Or with an alternate `getNumbers` that is more concise, but makes more loops through the input (which usually doesn't matter):

```
function getNumbers(str) {
    return str.split("")
        .filter(function(ch) { return /\d/.test(ch); })
        .map(function(ch) { return +ch; });
}

function division() {
    var numbers = getNumbers(document.getElementById("numbers").value);
    if (numbers[1] == 0) {
        throw new Error("Division by zero error");
    }
    return numbers[0] / numbers[1];
}
```

Comment: @ T.J Crowder, thnx a lot, but one more thing.... Will the try exception be visible in the console?

Comment: Because in my browser console, I cannot see the "bad" exception

Comment: @Siddhantinf: Not if you suppress it, no. In general, handled exceptions (which is what that was) are not reported to the console.

Comment: Okay, thnx a lot sir

Comment: @Siddhantinf: Happy to help. I've added a bit to the end of the answer, just FWIW.